# Qt local server to open webpages

Tags: qt, localhost, server, tcpserver

I created a Qt application which generates html files (with javascipt) and I want to launch the created page from the application. I can do it with QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(file)); but the problem is that I need a local server to make it work correctly.

I found that it's possible to do it with Qt but I am a bit lost between QTcpServer/Socket, QUdpSocket, QLocalServer/Socket, ... as I don't know anything about network.

I tried a very simple thing based on some examples I saw but I know I am far from the solution. Here is what I did :

```
void createServer(){
    server=new QTcpServer(0);
    connectionOK=server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost,0) ;
    cout<<server->serverPort()<<endl;
    connect(server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(openHTML()));
}

void openHTML(){
    cout<<"openHTML()"<<endl;
}
```

Then, when I open my browser and go to http://localhost:serverPort, the application ouputs "openHTML()". But I don't know how to open my web page on this server, and of course, http://localhost:serverPort/myPage.html doesn't work.

I looked at the Fortune example in Qt but it seems too complicated for what I need, but maybe I am wrong and I should take a better look at.

Comment: why don't you display your HTML files in a [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html)?

Comment: Why do you need a local server to open a simple html file? A TcpServer is used for network communication between different machines. You do not need anything like that for opening an html page. Please elaborate why you think you need one and what does not work by using the `QDesktopServices` approach

Comment: In fact, my webpage contains some functionalities that don't work locally without a local server (for example, video texture in webgl). It's due to security issues in the web browsers. So to open my page, I use WAMP but I would like to integrate a local server in my app so that I don't need WAMP anymore.

Comment: You can use existing Qt-based libraries, for example, [this one](http://www.hobrasoft.cz/en/blog/bravenec/httpd).

Comment: @Pavel Stakhov ok I'll have a look at that lib.

Comment: @Bowdzone I found an application which do exactly what I want to do, if it can help to understand what my goal is. It's the krpano testing server www.kolor.com/wiki-en/Panotour_-_FAQ_-_Viewing_the_tour_offline . You launch it, open a file and the app create a local server to open this page in a web browser at http://ipAdress:port/page.html

Comment: @SteveTJS Still, you need to create a webserver, not a Tcp server as far as I understand ist. I do not know of any Qt thing built in for such a purpose

Comment: I am also very interested in this kind of setup. Basically I want some Qt process running in the background, but accessible via some webpage in a  standard browser (thus not QWebkit). Ideally I would like my remote webpage http://mywebsite.com to check if this server is available locally and start communicating as well. Is this what you imagine @SteveTJS?

Comment: @Jacob Block It's not really what I want. What you want is more like a webservice application : your app is on a machine, and you want to communicate with it via the web on another machine. What I want is to launch a webserver locally to open webpages (requiring a server to work) locally, so all is on the same machine (like the krpano testing server www.kolor.com/wiki-en/Panotour_-FAQ-_Viewing_the_tour_offline ). I didn't have time to work on it more since I posted my question.